# How implement LDAP login in wildfly web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, ldap, wildfly

How to implement LDAP authentication in a Java EE WildFly app? Are there any examples?

I'm new to Java EE and need to write an app using LDAP and I'm stuck. I read a book about developing in WildFly but there was no information about LDAP there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following step of operation will have to be performed for authenticating your application using LDAP (assuming that LDAP is already setup).

Creating a new security domain in `standalone.xml` file.

```xml
<security-domain name="LDAPAuth">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
      <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
      <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://localhost:389"/>
      <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
      <module-option name="bindDN" value="uid=admin,dc=acme,dc=com"/>
      <module-option name="bindCredential" value="secret"/>
      <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=People,dc=acme,dc=com"/>
      <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
      <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Roles,dc=acme,dc=com"/>
      <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
      <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
      <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
      <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
    </login-module>
  </authentication> 
</security-domain>
```

you will have to change the values accordingly

Now you will have to add the security context in your application's web.xml. Assuming that you only want users with `user` Role to login to your application then you can add something like this

```xml
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>HtmlAuth</web-resource-name>
                <description>application security constraints</description>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>Manager</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
            <realm-name>LDAPAuth realm</realm-name>
        </login-config>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role>
    </web-app>
```

you will have to place a  `jboss-web.xml` in your WEB-INF folder with the following content

```xml
    <jboss-web>
           <security-domain>java:/jaas/LDAPAuth</security-domain>
    </jboss-web>
```

you can find a wonderful tutorial on this subject [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/configure-jboss-with-ldap?showall=&start=1)

Comment: Thanks it works. I need to define my own groups for users( i can't use groups from LDAP). By default user got access only for read but i want to have two additional groups. One for administrator and second for deleopers. Do you know how to do that? Mapping for user->group i want to have in db.

Comment: @skoczo I think you can add something like this

`<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
  <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasource/datasourceName"/>
  <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select roleid, 'Roles' from user_roles where userid=?"/>
  <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
 </login-module>`

but I am not completely  sure about it, it would be better you can show some of your current implementation and open a new question

Comment: May i ask you how can i fetch the username and password in java than?