# Ldap authentication, load roles from local database

Tags: jakarta-ee, ldap, roles

I want to override groups from LDAP by groups from my local database. I have already configured LDAP realm.
Can you help me? I'm using wildfly(no spring lib).

By default i want to use "read-only" group for all users which don't have mapping for roles in local DB.

Edit: My configuration is like here: [How implement LDAP login in wildfly web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186681/how-implement-ldap-login-in-wildfly-web-app)

Can I create some class/bean where after LDAP auth i will do some modifications on User(ex. change group)?

Maybe it will be easier to use Spring?

Comment: Define 'override'. Do you want to load the roles from the database *into* LDAP? Or throw the LDAP roles away on each login and use what's in the database instead? You can do all that with JAAS `LoginModules,` but there's not enough information about your existing environment to be sure it applies.

Comment: Sorry for inaccuracy. I want to use roles from local DB instead of using roles from LDAP. So i will have table with mapping username -> role_id and i want to use it. Some of users will not exist in this table and they should got readonly group by default.

Answer (score 1):

> I have already configured LDAP realm.

You need to configure a ***JAAS*** realm, with at least two LoginModules:

- one that looks up the user in LDAP and tries to bind as him using the supplied password, and creates an appropriate `Subject` if it succeeds
- another that runs next that looks up the user in the database and populates the roles as required into the `Subject.`

Comment: I am new in JEE and Wildfly development. Can you provide some example or key words to search in google?

Comment: I found something like this https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LDAPSecurityRealmExamples
I can see here ldap realms but don't know how to discover groups from DB.

Comment: This is interesting: http://www.len.ro/work/jboss-and-ldap/. Do You think that could i use this example and after  lc.login(); replace group from LDAP to group from DB?