# Wildfly Authentication and Authorizaion from separate providers

Tags: security, jsf, jboss, ldap, wildfly

I am trying to set up **User Authentication and Authorization** on JBoss Wildfly 10.0.0.Final

I configured *standalone.xml* according to the documentation on the [JBoss developer wiki](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LDAPSecurityRealmExamples).

As this did not work, I put the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186681/how-implement-ldap-login-in-wildfly-web-app) into action.

The application is built using

- JSF 2.2
- Java 1.8
- CDI 1.1

on Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) for J2EE with the additional facets *Dynamic Web Modue*, *JavaScript*, *JAX-RS*, *JBoss Maven Integration* and *JPA*.

The Login.xhtml holds

```xhtml
<form id="login" class="form-login" method="POST" action="j_security_check">
    <h:inputText id="j_username" name="j_username" class="form-control" value="#{user.name}" pt:placeholder="User" pt:autofocus=""/>
    <h:message for="j_username" styleClass="errorMessage"/>
    <h:inputSecret id="j_password" name="j_password" class="form-control" value="#{user.password}" pt:placeholder="Password" />
    <h:message for="j_password" styleClass="errorMessage"/>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

From standalone.xml:

```xml
<security-domain name="LDAPAuth">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://internal.de:389"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
            <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=machine-account,ou=special,ou=Users,dc=internal,dc=DE"/>
            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="SECRET"/>
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=Users,DC=internal,DC=DE"/>
            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectClass=*))"/>
            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

And web.xml reads

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>protected</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>appuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>LDAP Authentication Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/Noauth.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>appsuser</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Finally, `<security-domain>java:/jaas/LDAPAuth</security-domain>` is set in jboss-web.xml

The database connection is set up via

`<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/postgres" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">`

and corresponding nodes inside.

The LDAP connection seemed to work properly, but in any case the client recieves an empty page.

The network transaction is as follows:

**(1)**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/protected/j_security_check
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
```

**(2)**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/protected/res/img/favicon.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
```

On the contrary, the frontend's directory layout is

```
[webapp]
    [protected]
    [res]
    [WEB-INF]
    Login.xhtml
    Noauth.xhtml
```

I do not understand what's going on under the hood. Moreover, I need to do *authorization* after the LDAP *authentication*. The authorization must be provided by another database which holds usernames and roles only, no passwords. This is mandatory. According to the (JBoss Documentation)[https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Using_JBoss_Login_Modules-Password_Stacking.html] password stacking is the way to go, but I cannot provide any password on the authorization database.

How can this be accomplished, and, even more important, why does the authorization behave in that way ?

Comment: Does it work in a plain non-jsf html file?

Comment: As Java EE security defines the *j_security_check* action for login forms which allows the web container to authenticate users, an application server is needed. Therefore, I don't know if it is possible to use *j_security_check* without servlets.

Comment: Plain html INSIDE a container... (so no jsf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no source for any roles. Therefore, the server will not set any permission the the protected resource.

In order to get the whole thing working, you will need to set up both authentication and authorization.

Let me summarize the process of setting it up:

**1. Step**

Set up a security domain via the administration interface of WildFly or directly in the standalone.xml at which the login-module node holds child nodes of type *module-option*. Yours is properly set up.

For a complete reference of the module properties check https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LdapExtLoginModule?_sscc=t

If you take the roles from the LDAP Server, *rolesCtxDN*, *roleFilter* and*roleAttributeID* are needed at least. If you retrieve them from another source, e.g. a database, you need *password stacking*:

**2. Step**

Set up the configuration for your web application:

The data submitted via POST to a URL path *j_security_check* is checked on the server side and a session ID is returned to the client via a cookie, using the Java Authentication and Authorization Service.

Your **jboss-web.xml** and **web.xml** are properly set up.

Take care of the following behaviour:

If the node

```xml
<auth-constraint>
    ...
</auth-constraint>
```

has no *role-name* nodes inside, no user will have access. If you put `<role-name>*</role-name>` into auth-contraint, any authenticated user is authorized.

**3. Step**

Set up the roles source. In your case, you need to add another login-module to the authentication node :

```xml
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/postgres"/>
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="NULL"/>
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT roleColumn, 'Roles' FROM rolesTable WHERE name=?"/>
    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
</login-module>
```

*Note about favicon*

Your page is most likely trying to access a protected ressource. The behaviour is explained on the following post:

https://www.gilluminate.com/2004/11/16/redirect-to-favicon-after-login-with-mozilla-problem/