# How to know reason for authentication fails? (JEE app on JBOSS)

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jboss, ldap, jaas

I am trying to use LDAP for authentication. I am using JBOSS EAP 6.4 as app server. My current configuration is like -

web.xml

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HtmlAuth</web-resource-name>
        <description>application security constraints
   </description>
        <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>LdapRealm</realm-name>  
  </login-config>
```

Where as in jboss standalong.xml file, I have created outbound connection like -

```
 <outbound-connections>  
        <ldap name="ldapqa" url="ldaps://myldapurl" search-dn="my ldap user" search-credential="my ldap password"/>  
    </outbound-connections>
```

and one security realms -

```
  <security-realm name="LdapRealm">  
             <authentication>  
                    <ldap connection="ldapqa" base-dn="my searchbase">  
                         <username-filter attribute="uid"/>  
                    </ldap>  
            </authentication>  
        </security-realm>
```

Now when I hit the secure URL, i get the BASIC popup but after correct entering I am unable to login.  How can I know the reason for not getting logged on. I have set the logging level as TRACE but still nothing is coming in my logs.
Also what mistake I have made here in configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How implement LDAP login in wildfly web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186681/how-implement-ldap-login-in-wildfly-web-app)

Comment: I have checked that link. even when I make changes suggested in that answer, I get the same behavior.